# SSMS table properties show an exception for Index space on every table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2016

When getting table properties from a SQL 2014 server (12.0.4449) using SSMS 2014 (12.0.4100) or 2016 (13.0.15600) on any database or table I get the following text for the "Index space" property on the Storage tab:

> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or
>   batch.

This is the error:

[image: Property accessor 'IndexSpace]

Comment: That's a .NET error...I've seen it it sometimes using LINQ when writing C#. If it's showing up in SSMS, it might mean there's a bug. I'd say contact Microsoft Support for this one.

Comment: This can also be caused by "add-ins" which are not supported with SSMS.

Comment: It isn't add-ins as the 2016 SSMS is "fresh out of the box".

Comment: Run a repair on SSMS, for 2016 try applying latest version "13.0.15600.2". Have you applied any of the updates for VS since you installed SSMS? I have had that cause issues and had to repair SSMS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like Haris commented, it's likely an SSMS bug that Microsoft will have to resolve. But you should be able to run a trace or an Extended Event session to capture the TSQL that SSMS is using to get the data that you are after. Capture the TSQL and then run that in a query window. Or use [the query from marc_s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15896564/get-table-and-index-storage-size-in-sql-server).

Comment: Getting the data is not a problem - sp_spaceused will give me what I need. I've just never seen that issue before. What's more, I asked my co-worker with the same setup to get the props and he had no problem.

Comment: So he has the same exact SSMS build? Maybe a .NET build issue then?

Answer (score 1):

If possible, try to have your permissions level upgraded to `db_owner`, it can solve the issue.
That also explains why a co-worker with the same setup would be able to see the property but you don't.

But indeed, [`sp_spaceused`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-spaceused-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) should work without the extra permissions. Use with

```
sp_spaceused N'database_name.schema_name.table_name'
```

Comment: For anyone who downvotes, please explain what's wrong with this answer. I'm new to this site and can use some help!

Comment: Not sure why this answer received a down vote. I tried it and connecting with db_owner credentials fixed the issue for me (same machine).